# Is there a way to remotely shut down a Windows machine on my home network that doesn't support RDP?

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-access

I have an older Dell Dimension desktop, originally running Windows XP, that I had recently upgraded to Windows 8.1. I plan on using it as a media server running Plex, and I can easily move files on to it over my home network and update the library through the Plex web admin. I would also like to be able to shut down the machine when I’m not using it.

I don’t want to plug a monitor and a keyboard into it, so I’m not sure how I can do this, since remote desktop is apparently only available in Windows 8.1 Pro for some reason. The only thing I can think of is to set up a web server that runs some highly-trusted code that can invoke the shutdown command on the host, but I imagine there is a simpler way.

Comment: What about`shutdown /i`after`cmdkey /add:`?

Comment: I use and like [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) to do remote desktop to the computer I use as media server.

Comment: I wonder if the system power settings, and making the system hybernate might be a less complex solution. Not sure how the timers work headless tho.

Comment: _"remote desktop is apparently only available in Windows 8.1 Pro"_ lol really? how dumb

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, it's just not there, and that's what I've read. I was surprised, too.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler approach could go the other way: run a job on the machine that periodically polls some outside source and executes `shutdown` if so.  For instance, if you have a web server somewhere, you could create a file that the machine would fetch over http, and shut down if it contains some magic text.  When you want it to stay up, you change the file appropriately.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Microsoft considers the ability to Remote Desktop into a Windows machine an enterprise feature and therefore only includes it in the more expensive Professional edition. But then here at Super User we like to push our software beyond its limits, don't we?

Comment: More to the point, Microsoft considers that on the whole people who *need* RDP have more money than people who don't, and so it makes sense as one of the features used in their differential pricing model. It's "dumb" to the extent (if any) that Microsoft loses money as a result. I think "enterprise feature" generally amounts to "stuff you can live without unless you're one of the kind of customers liable to have money to throw at the problem".

Comment: @user2284570 I'm not following. That would require a keyboard, right? I don't want to use any peripherals.

Comment: @regularmike : Yes but you run those built‑in commands on the host machine, not the target. Once you added an administrator password account password with`cmdkey` you have full control of the machine silently.`shutdown /i`is only one example of you can do. There is nothing to install on both machines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

VNC ([TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) or many other flavors) is a freeware graphical remote control solution like Remote Desktop you wanted to use. It supports Windows 8.x.  VNC though a SSH tunnel is recommended for usage across the Internet.

Alternatively if you enjoy the command line, try running an SSH server on your media server. You can then run an ssh client (like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) which would allow the automation of file transfers and access to the command line with high security.  Inside of an ssh session or even directly from another Windows machine, you can use the [shutdown command-line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx).  This allows you to shut down or restart a local or remote computer.

For a low-tech solution, try holding the power button down quickly for a second or less (not the 5 seconds for a hard power off). Windows should shutdown gracefully or go into standby, depending on configuration.

As Peterh mentioned, you can also use telnet a command-line interface built-in to windows.  See control panel, add-remove programs.  While telnet is insecure for a home network it is a possibility.  SSH is the recommended secure encrypted alternative that only takes a little longer to setup.

Comment: There's no need to hold the power button and risking pressing it for too long. A single press for less than a second is sufficient.

Comment: @AndréBorie Thanks, that is a better explanation, updated.

Comment: You could also consider using freenas instead of windows as the OS

Comment: VNC is not very secure, especially when over the Internet.

Comment: @SiyuanRen these are just machines on my home network. I'm not opening anything up to the outside world.

Answer (score 47):

Such "highly trusted" code already exists.

- The `shutdown` tool can do remote shutdowns over RPC, as long as File Sharing is enabled:

  ```
  shutdown /m \\plexbox /s /t 0 /f
  ```

  Its Linux Samba equivalent:

  ```
  net rpc -S plexbox -f -t 0
  ```

  (Note that this needs SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege separate from the regular "local shutdown" privilege – even if you use it locally. This can be granted to non-admins via `secpol.msc`.)
- The WinRM (WS-Management) remote management interface is built into current Windows versions and supports running arbitrary commands remotely:

  ```
  :: Start the WinRM service
  sc \\plexbox start winrm

  :: Run a remote command
  winrs -r:plexbox shutdown /s /t 0 /f
  ```
- The same WinRM also carries [PowerShell Remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx) which can be used to run PowerShell commands:

  ```
  PS> Start-Service WinRM -ComputerName plexbox
  PS> Invoke-Command plexbox { shutdown /s /t 0 /f }
  ```

  PowerShell also has a dedicated command to shut down a remote system (I believe this uses WinRM/PSRemoting, not the RPC API like 'shutdown'):

  ```
  PS> Stop-Computer plexbox
  ```
- [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) was the usual tool for running programs remotely before WinRM:

  ```
  C:\> psexec -es \\plexbox shutdown /s /t 0 /f
  ```
- You can install an SSH server such as [Bitvise WinSSHd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) (or the Win32-OpenSSH service that is now built into Windows 10 or later).
- Finally, as GeraldB also wrote, there are other graphical remote control tools besides RDP – such as VNC, TeamViewer, radmin, etc.

Comment: @Andy  I am unfamiliar with File Sharing.  Why do you say that?

Comment: @Andy without underestimating your comment, your comment should have a backup, it's like saying "do not buy apples" is not constructive.

Comment: @Andy The question discusses using Plex "on their home network" and not over the internet, which is the usual use case for Plex. I don't think we're talking about exposing anything over the internet here, just within the local network.

Comment: @ChrisHayes yes you are right, i missed that.  You can connect to plex from the internet though, that's one of the features of the paid license.  Francisco, windows file sharing (smb) is terribly insecure, my comment was closer to "don't eat rat poison"

Comment: Since the goal is to shut down the target computer, `psshutdown` would probably be a more appropriate choice than `psexec`.

Comment: @grawity What do you mean about PSEXEC *I can't get it working with Active Directory anymore*?

Comment: @Twisty: Exactly that? Not sure if it's caused by AD, or by Samba as AD DC, or by whatever, but I get a very obscure error message from it.

Comment: @grawity Sounds like a good SF question I just may have an answer for

Comment: @Twisty SF as in ServerFault? Don't I need to manage a multinational network to ask questions there?

Comment: Instead of `net rpc -S plexbox -f -t 0` , did you mean `net rpc -S plexbox SHUTDOWN -f -t 0` ?

Comment: @Twisty: (For the record, the psexec problem seems to have been caused by Samba missing an implementation of the BackupKey protocol; 4.4 does not have this problem anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option for remote control, in addition to RDP and VNC, is services like [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com), [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/), [WebEx](http://www.webex.com/) or other similar [alternatives to screensharing](http://alternativeto.net/software/logmein/).

These options, like VNC, generally involve installing a client. You can then use their service to log into a computer remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Start menu, control panel, and or remove software / windows components. Click add / remove windows components.

Find "telnet server" in the tree, and enable it. For now, you can get a remote command line with any telnet client (I would suggest either the telnet client in windows, can be enabled there, too), or putty (can work as a telnet client as well).

Logging there remotely you can halt / restart your machine with the common `shutdown ...` commands.

But beware: telnet is among the most cracked protocols of the internet, because it send everything (incl. passowords) unencrypted. Thus I highly suggest to combine this solution with an encrypting VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can write a Python script that listens on a port via sockets (must port forward if you'd like to access from anywhere) and you can issue it commands via a Python socket client or through a PHP `socket_write()` to execute an appropriate task aka `shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

Native windows solution (even works on ɴᴛ4). Very Simple. No need to install anything.

1. If the machines aren’t member of the same active directory domain you’ll need to run this command the first time as an administrator on the host machine (it will be added permanently) : cmdkey /add:`Netbios name or ip target address` /user:`a local administrator account name existing on the target machine` /pass:`password of the account`

ꭥ
 2. Then and for all the time you will need it, simply run`shutdown /i`. (Sorry but I can’t change the language)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to make a hardwar for it, buy a simple hardware and plug and play this will help you to turn on off your pc.
you need following hardware/items

1. relay modle for arduino
2. esp32 module
3. an internet connection to turn on off remotly
4. suitable power suply for that two modules
5. a little software, you may then use your smartphone to turn on off and check status
   let me khow if you need help

Comment: This is an interesting method in theory, but it lacks the information necessary to make this an actual answer to the question posed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this tool (an early version, but fully functional):

https://github.com/r4zv4n/PlexShutDown

It will allow you to remotely shutdown the PlexMediaServer computer, by playing a a custom title from your library.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.